# Symfony Messenger: Retrying failed messages when using a message interface as the handler __invoke type-hint

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-messenger

I'm using the Symfony Messenger component in a Symfony 4.4 application. I'm processing the messages async through RabbitMQ and storing the failed ones in a database through the Doctrine transport.

And this is the messenger config:

```
framework:
    messenger:
        failure_transport: failed

        buses:
            command_bus:
                middleware:
                    - doctrine_ping_connection

        transports:
            failed: 'doctrine://default?queue_name=failed'
            async_priority_high:
                dsn: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
                retry_strategy:
                    delay: 2000
                    max_retries: 5
                    multiplier: 2
                options:
                    exchange:
                        name: high
                    queues:
                        messages_high: ~

            async_priority_low:
                dsn: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
                retry_strategy:
                    delay: 3000
                    max_retries: 3
                    multiplier: 2
                options:
                    exchange:
                        name: low
                    queues:
                        messages_low: ~

        routing:
            'App\SampleMessageButHighPriority': async_priority_high
            'App\SampleMessageInterface': async_priority_low
            'App\OtherMessage': async_priority_low
```

Here is a sample handler that handler messages imlpementing the `SampleMessageInterface` interface.

```php
final class SampleMessageHandler implements MessageHandlerInterface
{
    private ProjectRepository $projectRepository;

    public function __construct(ProjectRepository $projectRepository)
    {
        $this->projectRepository = $projectRepository;
    }

    public function __invoke(SampleMessageInterface $message): void
    {
        $project = $this->projectRepository->find($message->getProjectId()->toString());

        if ($project === null) {
            return;
        }

        $this->someProcessor->__invoke($project);
    }
}
```

Everything is working before facing any message failure. The problem starts showing after failing when trying to retry or show the failed messages. Let's try the `php bin/console messenger:failed:show` command:

Result:

```
In PhpSerializer.php line 64:
                                                                               
  Cannot instantiate interface App\SampleMessageInterface
```

I guess that Symfony needs to unserialize the failed message, previously serialized and stored in the database, but can't do it because it's an interface.

How can I solve this? Is there any way to serialize the failed messages using the class implementation, not the interface?

Comment: Please do not give code into picture. use \`\`\`code\`\`\` to post your code formated

Comment: I'm sorry about that, I've just updated my question. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: https://github.com/opengento/magento2-gdpr/issues/43
Here it say this is a cache issue. Maybe you have already try to clean the cache ? And why did you use ``final`` key word ?

Comment: Doc : https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#creating-a-message-handler

Didn't use final key word

Comment: Possible help next config:
```
messenger
  serializer:
    default_serializer: "messenger.transport.symfony_serializer"
```
Worked for me. In 4.2 there was it, but after in 4.4 (maybe earlier, didn't check), it changed to phpSerializer as a default. So just set it and should work

Answer (score 1):

Failed messages are stored serialized in the database. When you retry or show these messages they are deserialized.

Simply replace interface `SampleMessageInterface` to class `SampleMessage`.

Comment: But then how can I benefit from creating only one handler to handle all the ```SampleMessageInterface``` messages? Or it's impossible,  and I should start creating one handler for each ```SampleMessageInterface``` implementation?

Comment: You can, but look like there is a bug in messenger's failed transport feature. Could you please check the database with failed messages and say what is `type` in `headers` column? Is it `SampleMessageInterface` or something else?

Comment: It's ```SampleMessageInterface```, so I guess this is why it's not able to unserialize to the dispatched message imlpementation. I don't know if it's a bug or the expected behavior.

Comment: I think it's a bug. Shouldn't be an issue to serialize with the actual class name, not interface name.

Comment: I've just reported it, let's see what Symfony people say. Thanks!